# Silhouette score from k-medoids with gower matrix data

Tags: python, matrix

I try to calculate the silhouette score to 1 to 10 clusters with for i clause, but while trying to calculate the silhouette score:

with ***data_gower*** I get: `ValueError: bad input shape (1, 707)`

with ***distArray*** I get:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.20401523 0.26294225 0.26405147 ... 0.21941337 0.20577586 0.10499758].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."
```

I'm using the following code:

```
data_gower = gower.gower_matrix(orig_df_w_707rows_11cols_fwhich_2categorical)
distArray = ssd.squareform(data_gower) 
pam_silh = []
int_med = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for i in range(1, 11)  :
    # calculate the model with i
    kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(data_gower, int_med[:i], data_type = 'distance_matrix')
    kmedoids_instance.process()
    clusters = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
    medoids = kmedoids_instance.get_medoids()
    # calculate silhouette score and store it for graph 
    silhouette = silhouette_score(**data_gower or disarray**, clusters)
    pam_silh.append(silhouette)

pam_silh
```

Answer (score 0):

For future generations, I managed to solve this issue by realizing that my cluster calculation returned a list instead of array, which is needed to silhouette_score. by changing the **get_clusters** to **predict**, I was able to calculate the score.

```
pam_silh = []
int_med = [582, 5, 605, 50, 100, 434, 156, 189, 270, 502]
distArray = ssd.squareform(data_gower) 

for i in range(1, 11)  :
    # calculate the model
    kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(data_gower, int_med[:i+1], data_type = 'distance_matrix')
    kmedoids_instance.process()
    clusters_kmedoid = kmedoids_instance.predict(data_gower)
    # calculate silhouette score and store it for graph 
    silhouette = silhouette_score(data_gower, clusters_kmedoid)
    pam_silh.append(silhouette)

pam_silh
```